# identity server after valid token saying unauthorized 401

Tags: c#, identityserver4

after getting token from identity server I am calling the API

getting this error

[image: 1]

i am defining the Api scopes as  "patient/*.read"
in client scopes as well as in api scope table while in api resources table i am entering the resource Name as "fhir.patient.access.api" and passing the same OAuthAppName in startup.cs

any one can help me for this??

also i want to authorize client for one api this
Api

[image: 2]

but i want the same client unauthorized for another api in another controller or in same controller

Comment: is there no one to guide????

Comment: 401 means that the received token is not valid (wrong audience), do check what the aud claim in the access token is and make sure you have the same in the JwtBearer config.

Comment: that issue is resolved....... all apis are getting called now
audience was not valid... so it worked for this patient/*.read... but it working for all the api

now  i want to authorize a client for one api but want the same client unauthorized for another api...